# Signing for a jwt web token returns null - nodejs

Tags: node.js, jwt, access-token

The jwt signing fails and returns a null for token. Here is my implementation:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var jwt_session_secret = "rnwR_apwvkWjdHovcmmQuoDwLR8av9oFjbJm2KhS7oEX9aSiBu9e96jxCDM9vj5_x8OlCCEiXwIGkagL-KDgnDsulc2e0QU5qYN75lzomrc4P9gqgGXB7HVfpaBcKgW3oLsXRBWAoFT5ICsOSwT-70hdQtJfE7a3NK6j3jmxcSE";

var payload = { ud: 23 };
var exp = Math.floor((new Date(+new Date + 12096e5).getTime())/1000);
var opts = { issuer: 'gateway', expiresIn: exp };

console.log(payload);

jwt.sign( payload, jwt_session_secret, opts, function(token) {

    console.log("token = " + token);

        jwt.verify(token, jwt_session_secret, function(err, decoded) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Error failed: " + err);
                return;
            }
            console.log("decoded");
            console.log(decoded);
            });
        });
```

The code looks good to me but not sure if im missing something here. This is the output:

`{ ud: 23 }
token = null
Error failed: JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept two parameters in the callback, **err** and **token** as follow:

```
jwt.sign( payload, jwt_session_secret, opts, function(err, token) {
```